# Which motors are specifically used for UR3 (Universal robot arm)

Tags: robotic-arm, manipulator

I am looking for the specification of UR3, peak torque and rpm.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Muhammad Usman, but I'm afraid that questions which can only be answered by the pre-sales or technical support team for a specific manufacturer or supplier aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. *[Practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)* are always welcome here though, so if you edit your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you. Please take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. I will check it. 
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [technical specs](https://www.universal-robots.com/media/240787/ur3_us.pdf) sheet publicly provided by Universal Robots doesn't list the RPM or peak torque. When this is the case, I find it beneficial to simply call the manufacturer/developer for more technical information. Fortunately, at the bottom of the technical specs sheet, a phone number is provided.